# How can I most easily authenticate with gspread in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: google-oauth, jupyter-notebook, gspread, google-colaboratory

Many of my partners at work are comfortable mainly with spreadsheets, and not python, scala, java, SQL, etc. These people are non-technical, but they need data and it's my job to get it in their hands. Reading about Google colaboratory, and [their example notebook on io](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb&scrollTo=WgXqE02UofZG), I discovered gspread and the apparent ease of authentication:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())
```

We use a local deployment of Jupyter with several customizations for simplifying access to Presto, Hive, Spark, etc, so I tried installing colab in our environment to no avail (it's not open source). The next best approach I found was [using oauth2](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html), but this seems to require a GCP account for access to the [Google Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard). This seems overly complicated for something that boils down to authenticating with a remote service.

So, group mind, how do *you* most easily authenticate with gspread in a jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 2):

I can explain the ingredients that make this work in Colab:

- the call to `authenticate_user` invokes `gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access` (with [other args](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/567c722bec8c0b933d015c00b884f365f5d2dd34/google/colab/auth.py#L49)).
- We then set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to an exported copy of those credentials.
- Any code using the [Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) can now discover those credentials; in particular, `oauth2client` finds them (as in the sample above).

As always, you should be careful about where you put credentials; in the case of Colab, we have a fairly controlled system, and are OK with this setup (though as with all things, it could change in the future).